# Как добавить определенное количество нулей в конце?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста как добавить определенное количество нулей в конце?

```
// пример
var sec = 0.015;
var pre = 6;
var res = "0.015000"; // как получить такое значение имея выше данные?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function padZeros(v, p) {
  let res = v.toString().split('.');
  if (res.length == 1)
    res.push('');
  res[1] = res[1].padEnd(p, '0');
  return res.join('.');
}

console.log(padZeros(0.015, 5));
console.log(padZeros(0.015, 6));
console.log(padZeros(15, 5));
```

Comment: Спасибо, вроде правильно считает, хотел toPrecision использовать, но почему то как то не правильно добавляет нули

Comment: @Serge88 "почему то как то не правильно добавляет нули" - потому что большинство населения (включая программистов) не понимают разницы между "точностью" и "количеством цифр после запятой (точки)"

Answer (score 5):

можно вот так попробовать

```js
// пример
const sec = 0.015;
const pre = 5;
const res = sec.toPrecision(pre)

console.log(res)
```

Comment: pre = 5; у меня на выводе 0.015000, 5 это уже получается должно быть 0.01500, тоесть имелось виду нужно дополнение недостающими нулями

Comment: да, вариант не оптимальный, для оптимального нужно работать со строками, есть правда проблема с float числами - при перевод в строку оно может оказаться не таким как при записи, например `1.399999999` вместо `1.4` (взял от балды, чтобы не искать такие числа), как тогда быть с нулями?

Comment: пробовал его использовать, наверное эта функция для чего то другого предназначена, с float постояно одни проблемы с точностью

Comment: там не проблемы, просто там двоичная система, а вы хотите результат видеть в десятичной, поэтому часто если в двоичной число конечно, то в десятичной оно имеет бесконечную запись и наоборот поскольку 2^n = 10 и n - иррациональное число, поэтому по хорошему число надо переводить в строку округлять откидывать лишние цифры и заполнять нулями